# Spaceship Character controller stuck in wall

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

I am making a spaceship flying game where you navigate it through cave tunnels. The problem is best displayed in the video here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0K2WdeL7f0A

The movement is controlled using a character controller and a script. The script only calls `controller.Move(<vector>)`, where the vector can be in any direction.

The character controller settings are:

```
Slope Limit: 180
Step Offset: 0.5
Skin Width: 0.3
Min Move Distance: 0
Center: (0,0,0)
Radius: 3
Height: 0.5
```

The collider is effectively a sphere. I also checked that `collisionFlags` says that its touching sides. I also made the collider physicMaterial have 0 friction and added a bit of bounciness (0.5). But irrespective of all of this, I am not able to prevent the character from getting stuck.

How can I prevent the character from getting stuck in the wall?

Comment: Thank you for submitting the status report. Was there a *question* you meant to ask?

Comment: What is the body of controller.Move method?

Comment: If it uses transform functions to move the character then it overrides physics engine calculations. So using `rigidbody.AddForce(directionVector)` instead of transform functions will probably solve the issue.

Comment: @Bahman_Aries: I doesn't use transform functions, in fact there is no rigidbody attached at all - as it uses CharacterController. As I mentioned, I call CharacterController::Move()

Comment: @spencer7593: Spaceship getting stuck is not intended behaviour - the walls should just prevent movement perpendicular to their surface, not prevent movement along them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, after some experimentation. Since I controlled the ship movement using translate deltas, I maintained my own Vector3 variable for velocity. The problem was that on collision, I didn't update the velocity vector to slow down in the direction of the collision. The following code solved it:

```
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    float velocityReduction = Vector3.Dot(velocity, hit.normal);
    velocity = velocity - velocityReduction * hit.normal;
}
```